# Ошибка #ERROR при запуске пользовательской формулы

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

В одной таблице все нормально при добавлении пользовательской функции `countCellsWithBackgroundColor` подсчет ячеек идет. А во второй таблице не работает. В ячейке отображает `#ERROR`. В чем может быть проблема?

```
function countCellsWithBackgroundColor(color, rangeSpecification) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);

  var x = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {

    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {

      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);

      if (cell.getBackgroundColor() == color)

        x++;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Информации недостаточно. Что за Таблицы? Как ведется расчет? Как повторить проблему?

Comment: Таблицы с разными данными google spreadsheet стандартные. там есть всего 1 скрипт. я его описал выше. создаю ячейки закрашенные в зеленый цвет. и прописываю, к примеру =countCellsWithBackgroundColor("#00ff00","N2:N5"). на выходе получаю  EROR(Синтаксическая ошибка в формуле). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14MUo6b1xMbHIOXztIQ4K8eQfLVEDwBWtweva_klTtPA/edit?usp=sharing
В другой таблице делаю тоже самое и все работает. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L7Hz2Ny4leLX2r1dsGN7LSbaap8g6cImTwTJDfn8oeM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение `#ERROR` указывает на синтаксическую ошибку формулы.

Скорей всего, необходимо рассматривать само написание формулы в Таблице, а не скрипт. Попробуйте поставить точку с запятой как разделитель аргументов

```
=countCellsWithBackgroundColor("#00ff00"; "N2:N5")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это зависит от локальных настроек Таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!